# Populate ComboBox with Each FileType From Computer

Tags: vb.net

I want to display one of each & every file extensions in computer to combobox. My coding as follows.

```
Dim comboBox1 As New ComboBox()
    Dim caminho As String = "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Test\"
    Dim dir As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(caminho)
    Dim extensions as string = dir.GetFiles().[Select](Function(fi) fi.Extension).OrderBy(Function(ext) ext, StringComparer.CurrentCulture).Distinct(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase).ToArray()
    comboBox1.Items.AddRange(extensions)
```

I found error Expression Expected near `Function`   Why I'm getting that error.

I'm using VB2005 & I added System.Collections namespace also.

Comment: `extensions` is declared as `String` instead of `String()`. You can use type inference to determine the result: `Dim extensions = dir.GetFiles(). [...]` -- When you'll try to get *each & every file extensions in computer* you'll have more *subtle* problems than that.

Comment: Thnk You Jimi. I change that statement 'Dim extensions as string() = dir.GetFiles().[Select](Function(fi) fi.Extension).OrderBy(Function(ext) ext, StringComparer.CurrentCulture).Distinct(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase).ToArray()' But The error not corrected.

Comment: I don't remember (or, I just don't know) whether your version of VB.Net supports Lambda expressions. That code seems to come from a C# conversion, because of the (useless) `.[Select]`. Did you add a reference to System.Linq? -- Note that Visual Studio 2019 Community edition is free software.

Comment: Yes I add System.Data.Linq

Comment: `System.Linq`, not `System.Data.Linq`. Requires .Net Framework 3.5+ -- Since you can reference that latter, you can also reference the former. `IEnumerable<T>`  requires `System.Collections.Generic`

Comment: I added System.Collections.Generic. But my framework 2.0 I think I cannot use System.Linq.

Comment: How did you add a reference to `System.Data.Linq` then? It has the same .Net requirements. -- It's probably time to update your Visual Studio and language version (past due) -- BTW, the current User's Desktop (physical) folder is `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)` -- You can probably target .Net Framework 3.5 in VS 2005. I really don't know if it's supported directly.

Comment: System.Data.Linq is there. Any way Is there any way to do my requirement ? I can display all the file extensions in folder. But I cannot display one of each extension.

Comment: The code you have there already does that -- If you can reference `System.Data.Linq`, you can also reference `System.Linq` -- But you probably don't have a working reference to `System.Data.Linq` (which is useless here). -- If you actually cannot target .Net Framework 3.5+, you can use a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`, where the `Key` is the file extension. Loop the files, check `ContainsKey()`, if it's not there then add it. The `Value` can be used to count of duplicates. Or use an [ICollection<T>](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icollection-1) object.